# SQL Server LDAP authentication

Tags: .net, sql-server, ldap

Using SQL Server 2005, how can I authenticate a username/password pair against a non-AD LDAP server using NET ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If calling from SQL Server 2005, you'll need to create a .NET stored procedure.

Using .NET to connect to LDAP:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx

```
using System.DirectoryServices;

DirectoryEntry DE = new DirectoryEntry(LDAPPath, LDAP_Domain + account, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

if (DE == null)
{
   // Login failure
}
```

Comment: Hi Darryl,

Unfortunately, the System.Directory set of assemblies/services aren't available to SQL via the CLR services.

Comment: You can access the assembly, but it considered an "Unsupported Library".  I've included a couple of URLs about this.

http://dbaspot.com/forums/ms-sqlserver/218655-system-directoryservices-allowable-clr.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx