# C# Offering Different Types of Authentication in Custom Application

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, authorization, identity

I am building a client side application in C# that contains an authorization system based on a database.

The authentication is abstracted through an interface like:

```
public interface IAuthorizationRequest {
    bool IsUserValid(string userName, string password);
}
```

I understand how to use C# to query active directory, but was wondering how I would associate the active directory account for a user to the database authentication system I already provide. If a user would like to integrate their authentication with their Active Directory system instead of using my built in authentication how can I provide this?

Also, I assume I'd still need the database of users in order to store preferences and profile information. Is their some sort of unique Active Directory identifier that I can retrieve using C# to tie the user account to the Active Directory account?

Is it considered proper to more or less import the Active Directory users into the application and create local application user accounts tied to the corresponding Active Directory entry?

I have been scouring the web for this answer but the issue seems that I don't really know how to formulate the question that I am asking.

Note: I am not looking to use ASP.NET authentication providers because this is a client side application with a centralized database server.

I have been looking into WIF (Windows Identity Foundation) but wasn't sure if this was the best approach.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579359/sql-server-ldap-authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the AD user name into your user table, as mentioned by @Wiktor, and I would try using Dependency Injection to choose which authentication model to employ for a given user (assuming the user is directly choosing which model to use, say from radio buttons or dropdown).

Answer (score 1):

WIF would help you to build web applications but it seems that it is not your choice.

If I understand correctly, you are building a Windows application? If this is so, why don't you stick with integrated authentication? Your users don't have to log into the application as they are already authenticated by the operating system. You can just ask for the current user's credentials with `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`.

If integrated authentication is not an option, you still can work with the AD, this link could get you started:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx

And the last thing - yes, you have to somehow assign one of the AD attributes to your user table so that whenever the AD user logs into your application, you can identify him/her in your database. Importing accounts in advance could be an option or you can create accounts "on the fly". If however, users are already present in your database and the AD integration is just another form of authentication, you can ask your users to log using existing credentials (stored in your database), ask for their AD identity and if both authentication sources validate succesfully, you can merge the information from the AD into the user record.